# Time Series Forecasting using Random Forest in R

Tags: r, random-forest, forecasting, predict

I'm trying to do a time series analysis using randomforest. PFB my code

```
Subsales<-read.csv('Sales.csv')
head(Subsales)
```

Sample Data:

```
Date               SKU                            City   Sales
      <date>                               <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
1 2014-08-11 Vaseline Petroleum Jelly Pure 60 ml Jeddah1   378
2 2014-08-18 Vaseline Petroleum Jelly Pure 60 ml Jeddah1   348
3 2014-08-25 Vaseline Petroleum Jelly Pure 60 ml Jeddah1   314
4 2014-09-01 Vaseline Petroleum Jelly Pure 60 ml Jeddah1   324
5 2014-09-08 Vaseline Petroleum Jelly Pure 60 ml Jeddah1   352
6 2014-09-15 Vaseline Petroleum Jelly Pure 60 ml Jeddah1   453


####Length of training & testing set Splitting it 80-20####

train_len=round(nrow(SubSales)*0.8) 
test_len=nrow(SubSales)



######Splitting dataset into training and testing#####

#### Training Set
training<-slice(SubSales,1:train_len) 
#### Testing Set
testing<-slice(SubSales,train_len+1:test_len)

training=training[c(1,4)]
testing=testing[c(1,4)]

library(randomForest)
set.seed(1234)
regressor = randomForest(formula=Sales~.,
                data=training,
                ntree=100)

y_pred = predict(regressor,newdata = testing)
```

I'm getting a stationary result when I use the predict function on test data set.All predicted values are 369, I've tried for another data set I got the same result. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is supposed to be predictive of sales? At the moment I only see date, and two factors (product and city) with one level each. Start with some feature-engineering. For example, try to extract the day of the week from date and include that as a 7 level factor.

Comment: Without knowing where `slice` comes from, the `training` and `testing` datasets seem to be limited to 2 values. Perhaps a comma is missing to select the first and fourth column `training=training[, c(1,4)]`.

Comment: Also try with `testing<-slice(SubSales, (train_len+1) :test_len)` to see the effect of parenthesis  try `1+2:5` and compare with your expected result. Without parenthesis, the two slices essentially overlap defeating the purpose of separation. Would highly recommend `createDataPartition` function from `caret` package for such tasks

Comment: @nya No they aren't limited to 2 data values it's selecting the first and fourth columns.

Comment: @hNu My training and test set have been successfully created, there are no problems with them. I would like to know why am I getting stationary values when I use the predict function

Comment: @JanLauGe I'm just trying to do TS Analysis using RandomForest, There are two columns week and sales.

Comment: Is `369` the mean value of your Sales?

Comment: @JanLauGe Nope it isn't

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me try to rephrase your question to make sure I accurately understand what you want to do.

*You have sales per day for a product, and you would like to predict sales as a function of the date into the future. You do NOT have any predictive variables, such as number of customers, amount spent on advertising, or anything else. Your input data looks like this:*

```
Date        Sales
2014-08-11  378
2014-08-18  348
2014-08-25  314
2014-09-01  324
2014-09-08  352
2014-09-15  453
...
```

I think your RandomForest is behaving as expected. Random forest is a supervised machine learning algorithm that tries to predict `y` (response, here: Sales) given input variables `x` (predictors). Here, the only `x` you supply is date. However, each date is completely new to the random forest and the algorithm can therefore only guess that sales of your product on that day will be average.

You have two options:

**Option 1)** Stick with your approach of only using dates as predictors. You will need a different method, perhaps an autoregression approach such as ARIMA. This approach tries to detect trends in the data. Are sales more or less static, growing, or going down? Is there a weekly trend, a monthly trend, an annual trend? An example to get you started can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14742/auto-arima-with-daily-data-how-to-capture-seasonality-periodicity)

**Option 2)** Use data collection and feature engineering to create features that help your RandomForest to predict values for new dates. For example, try to get data on how many customers came to the store on any given day, or extract the day of the week (Monday, Tuesday, ...) and keep that as a separate variable. The R-package lubridate will help you do this. A brief example below:

```
library(lubridate)
Subsales <- mutate(Subsales, Weekday = wday(Date, label = TRUE))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps. I did not know how random forest works. I've already done TS using Arima and HoltsWinter I was just trying if it is possible to do with RandomForest. I thought I was making some mistake that's why I'm getting stationary values. Thanks again Cheers

Comment: I have a similar problem, Since I already have a ARIMA and exponential smoothing I would love to do in Randam Forest. Can you help me out of what is the approach @ShivamSarin

Comment: Do you have any data to use as predictors @Lalitha? Have a look at this blog post of mine, it does some forecasting on retail data. Happy to take this to private chat if you need more help.
https://janlauge.github.io/2017/exploring-sales-data/